# Is the boto module the only way to access config vars in Heroku apps?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, amazon-s3, boto

I'm deploying a flask webapp on heroku and I've created a heroku config var to store an admin key. The [heroku config var docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) say to use the boto module to access the config var from within the .py file in the following way:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
s3 = S3Connection(os.environ['S3_KEY'], os.environ['S3_SECRET'])
```

When I attempt to deploy with this in my code I get the following error:

```
raise boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound(
boto.exception.NoAuthHandlerFound: No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV1Handler'] Check your credentials
```

The [boto docs](https://boto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html#details) say I need to have ~/.aws/credentials, in the format:

```
[Credentials]
aws_access_key_id = <your_access_key_here>
aws_secret_access_key = <your_secret_key_here>
```

So I have a few questions about this:

1. Do I need to create AWS credentials to use boto?
2. How do I do so?
3. Does /.aws/credentials go in my main git repository when pushing to heroku?
4. Is there an alternative (easier) way to access heroku config vars from within .py code?

Comment: It's been 6 years since boto3 was released. I would say it's time to upgrade from boto2.

Comment: When I tried using boto3 I got a gunicorn error: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)

Comment: `boto` is an AWS library. It has _nothing at all_ to do with reading environment variables. You can do that with the standard library, e.g. via `os.enviorn` or `os.getenv`. You might want to _use the information you **got** from the environment_ with `boto`, e.g. here where you appear to be trying to connect to Amazon S3, but that's completely different.